# homogenous system has unique solution, transpose of coefficient matrix system has solution

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to start a problem or if my proof is correct. The problem is if $\textbf{Ax=0}$ has a unique solution, then the system $\textbf{A}^T\textbf{x=b}$ has a solution for every $\textbf{b}$. I'm trying to prove it by saying if there is a unique solution to the homogenous system then the system must be that $\textbf{x=0}$
\, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Remember to put "\$\$" signs around your equations...the latex was good, the \$... \$ was missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you let the columns of $A$ be $\mathbf a_1, \ldots, \mathbf a_n$, then $Ax$ can be written
$$
x_1\mathbf  a_1 + x_2\mathbf a_2 + \ldots + x_n\mathbf a_n = 0.
$$
Saying that this has a unique solution amounts to saying that the vectors $\mathbf a_i$ ($i = 1, \ldots, n$) are linearly independent. Does that tell you anything about the *rows* of $\mathbf A$?

Comment: Does this tell that the rows are linearly independent too because the pivots are all 1 and there are no free variables?

Comment: Well...something like that. The number of linearly independent rows is the same as the number of linearly independent columns.